# Iterate through two series in one line and then apply logic

Tags: python, pandas, loops, logic, series

I have two Pandas Series Height and Distance.

If height is greater than 500 i want to divide height by 10.
And the exact same to thing for Distance.

I tried this...

```
for i,j in map(None,Height, Distance):
if i > 500:
    i = i/10
else:
    i=i
if j > 500:
    j=j/10
else:
    j=j
```

Is there a way to do this in two logic statements instead of four?

```
if i,j > 500:
    i = i/10 
    j = j/10
else:
    i=i+10
    j=j+10
```

I get an error doing this

> if i,j > 500:
>           ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Note if I implement i > 500 and j > 500 it must satisfy both of those cases to work.

Comment: you are probably searching for : if i > 500 and j > 500:

Comment: @ncica Yes, to a degree. I edited my post.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to update your `i` and `j` values independent of each other, correct? You will not get your expected result if you combine both the `if` conditions into one. Also, why do you need the `else` block when you are not updating any values there?

Comment: @panktijk My objective is to do it in less lines. Both i and j are being compared to the same value, 500. I edited the else condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) from `numpy`, where you can specify update conditions in a single line for each series:

```
import numpy as np
# For each series, divide value by 10 if condition is true else add 10
Height = np.where(Height > 500, Height/10, Height+10)
Distance = np.where(Distance > 500, Distance/10, Distance+10)
```

Answer (score 0):

*NOTE: The question was edited and the usecase changed after this answer was written.*

You should not use a for-loop for this: they are slower and harder to read.

Try the following code instead:

```
Height[Height > 500] /= 10
Distance[Distance > 500] /= 10
```

This replaces the heights and distances above 500 with their value divided by 10. If you need to keep the values of the original you can simply make a copy first:

```
corrected_height = Height.copy()
corrected_height[corrected_height > 500] /= 10
```